# Google OR-tools: CVRP with collection and delivery, as well as reload option at depot

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am working with Google OR-tools in Python.

The problem I am facing is basically a mixture of:

1. creating both collecting and delivering dimensions for the CVRP (as in [Google OR-tools VRP - Pickup/Dropoff at same node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000884/google-or-tools-vrp-pickup-dropoff-at-same-node)) by having a demand and a load constraint, and
2. implementing a reload option at the depot (similar to https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py) as well as the possibility to drop orders with a penalty.

As an example, let's consider 1 vehicle with max_capacity=2 and the following 3 nodes (0 being the depot):

| Node | deliveries | collects | loads (deliveries + collects) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | -1 | 0 | -1 |
| B | -1 | 0 | -1 |
| C | -1 | 1 | 0 |

Assuming all points are equidistant, one solution would be:

0 (deliveries:2, load:2) --> C (1, 2) --> A  (0, 1) --> 0, dropping order B at the given cost/penalty.

However, I would like to implement the possibility to reload at 0, i.e., getting something like:

0 (deliveries:2, load:2) --> C (1, 2) --> A  (0, 1) --> 0 (1, 1) --> B (0, 0) --> 0.

I've tried to combine the two solutions mentioned above, by setting the slack capacities of both dimensions (deliveries and loads) at max_capacity.
However, my program always drops all the reload stations, even though dropping the additional orders is way more expensive.

Did someone already manage to solve the problem I am facing, or has any recommendations?